# Jquery loop each element in collection and run more than one commands on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have collection of jquery objects. I want to loop through each element, click on that element and close that element and then go to next object in the collection.

I have something like this: -

```
$("a.GetLink").not(".ImageLink")   //Get the collection of links on the page
.each(function(){
this.click()                //This is to click on first click
$("li.Current a.Close").click() //Then close that link and go to next link in the collection(It is on the same page)

})
```

Right now, it clicks on the first link and never closes it, instead it tries to click on second link after the first click.

Close link is available after the first click is clicked.

Comment: is it opening the link in a new tab/window?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle reproducing the issue? It is hard to speculate your dom structure

Comment: How is the association of `a.GetLink` and `a.Close`? that would be great if you can paste the HTML as well

Comment: More generally, is the close link visible before the click happens? If not, it could be a timing issue

Comment: 1. It opens in the same tab
2. is the close link visible before the click happens? If not, it could be a timing issue: - Close link is only visible after the click happens so can you tell me how do I solve this? StephenTG?